# How do you change the version of R running in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: r, visual-studio-2017, rtvs

I would like to run R version 3.4 instead of the current, 3.3.2, and don't really know where to begin.

Web searches left we with little, perhaps, though, because I am not used to working on the Windows 10 platform and don't fully understand how the components in Visual Studio are layered.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I hope this answers your questions.

In the bottom right of the VS console there will most likely stand R 3.3.2, if you click on it, a menu will pop up, allowing you to switch between the different versions available on your machine.

[image]

You will see in the bottom right, he is running Microsoft R Open 3.3.2, this is where you click to change versions

Comment: Aha, self-detection, exactly the logic I failed to understand. The updated version was installed, and detected, unproblematically. Kudos!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 11):

RTVS should detect all the versions of R you've got installed on your machine, in which case @pwjvr's answer is correct. You should be able to click on the workspace item in the corner and choose a different version to switch to. A "workspace" is what RTVS calls a specific R installation that can be used to run your code.

In the situation where RTVS doesn't detect R, you can add it manually. Go to the workspace window (R Tools -> Windows -> Workspaces). This should pop up a window like the one below.

[image]

Click on Add, and fill in the entries:

- Entry name: name you want to give this workspace
- Host URL or path: location of the R install, eg `C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.1`
- R command line arguments: any arguments to pass to the R binary. Generally you can leave this blank.

[image]

Comment: I just tried adding the newest version of Microsoft R Open 4.0.2 to Visual Studio 2017 that way, as the version I was using (Microsoft R Client 3.5.2.0) seems to not be able to get the most recent versions of some packages, but when I follow your instructions to add it I get the following error: "Connecting to R Workspace failed.
Reason: No R interpreters installed."

Comment: Just a note, newer versions of R cannot run on VS 2017.